# Please explain the loop below

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a GUI calculator by looking at my course video, but I am not able to understand what the "for loop" is doing in the code below.

```
 try:
    import tkinter
except ImportError: # python 2
    import Tkinter as tkinter

keys = [[('C', 1), ('CE', 1)],
        [('7', 1), ('8', 1), ('9', 1), ('+', 1)],
        [('4', 1), ('5', 1), ('6', 1), ('-', 1)],
        [('1', 1), ('2', 1), ('3', 1), ('*', 1)],
        [('0', 1), ('=', 1), ('/', 1)],
        ]

mainWindowPadding = 8

mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()
mainWindow.title("Calculator")
mainWindow.geometry('640x480-8-200')
mainWindow['padx'] = mainWindowPadding

result = tkinter.Entry(mainWindow)
result.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

keyPad = tkinter.Frame(mainWindow)
keyPad.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

row = 0
for keyRow in keys:
    col = 0
    for key in keyRow:
        tkinter.Button(keyPad, text=key[0]).grid(row=row, column=col, columnspan=key[1], sticky=tkinter.E + tkinter.W)
        col += key[1]
    row += 1
```

Comment: Which bit of the loop do you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This for loop is basically used for laying out the buttons on your window.

```
for KeyRow in keys :
```

repeats all the code in the loop the amount of times rows of keys are present in the list `keys` (in this case, there are 5 rows)

`col = 0` and `row = 0` are used for positioning the keys on the window.

```
for key in keyRow:
```

repeats all the code in the loop the amount of times a key is present in a row (eg. the first row has 2 keys, so the loop will repeat all the sub code twice etc...)

```
tkinter.Button(keyPad, text=key[0]).grid(row=row, column=col, columnspan=key[1], sticky=tkinter.E + tkinter.W)
```

This is for the positioning of the keys.

`col += key[1]` shifts the key position on the y axis by one every time a key is placed on a window and `row += 1`shifts the row position on the x axis by one every time a row of keys is placed on the window.

Hope this answers your question !